# Merge two large MySQL databases whilst maintaining referential integrity

Tags: mysql, merge

I have two large (6GB and 8GB respectively) MySQL databases which have identical schemas, and a common history up until about 6 weeks ago.

They differ from that point, and therefore, after that point, will have conflicting primary keys.

I want to merge these two databases - whilst maintaining referential integrity.

Initially, I tried to diff the databases using git, however git falls over when trying to resolve deltas on BLOBs within the databases.

Can anyone suggest a way of doing this?

**Edit**: Although it would have been a good idea at the time, I don't have any binary logs for either database

Comment: How many tables?  (I'm assuming no foreign key constraints since it's MySQL...)

Answer (score 0):

I think a good idea is make a script to migrate data and then iterate over the small database and add the records to the bigger database.

Make tests in a development environment and after confirm that it works, run in production.

Comment: Sounds good - however I think it will be difficult because of the ID references between tables